# organize windows layout on the screen (windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, window-manager

I've got a large screen and I wish to have a predefined layout for some of the programs I use.

For example, I want the skype to always open to a specific spot, and the chrome to another, and so on.

Is there a (free) software to manage that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.winsplit-revolution.com/

No longer available there but can be downloaded from http://winsplit-revolution.en.softonic.com/

Comment: This software works great - thank you!

Comment: No longer available :-( your link goes to a landing page pointing to other software that is only a free trial.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [MaxTo](http://www.maxto.net/). It's not free, though.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need this [Windows Manager](http://www.brain-dump.org/projects/dwm-win32/)

It has portable version and super light :)

Comment: I tried this software, but because my screen icon size are large - the software couldn't handle the big icons (thus there was no access to the menu options) - thank anyway

Comment: @akira thanks for your comment. I've edited the post :)